# Expectation of $\frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i^2}$ for iid r.v

Tags: probability, expected-value

I am looking to solve this exercise.

Let $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ be i.i.d random variables with pdf    $$\frac{\sqrt{\theta}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\theta x^2/2}$$

Determine the mean of   $\frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i^2}$.

**Question:** Can I say that since $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ are independent and identically distributed with a pdf of $\frac{\sqrt{\theta}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\theta x^2/2}$, we can write the denominator of the expression inside the expectation as follows:

\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i^2 &= X_1^2 + X_2^2 + \ldots + X_n^2 \\
&= \frac{1}{\theta}\left(\chi_{1}^2 + \chi_{2}^2 + \ldots + \chi_{n}^2\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{\theta}\chi_{n}^2.
\end{align*}

Where $\chi_{i}^2$ is a chi-squared random variable with one degree of freedom.

Therefore, we have:

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[\frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i^2}] &=  \frac{1}{\theta} E\left[\frac{1}{\chi_{n}^2}\right]\\
&= \frac{1}{\theta} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^2}\frac{1}{2^{1/2}\Gamma(1/2)}e^{-x^2/2} dx\\
&= \frac{1}{\theta} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/2} dx\\
&= \frac{1}{\theta} \cdot 1\\
&= \frac{1}{\theta}
\end{align*}

Therefore,  $ \mathbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i^2}\right] = \frac{1}{\theta}$.

Comment: @OliverDíaz Shouldn't it be $t^{-1}$ rather than $t^{-2}$ which results in $1/(n-2)$?

Comment: @JimB... but of course!

Comment: There is an error in the integral expression that represents $E[1/\chi^2_n]$: if $T\sim\chi^2_n$ then
$$
\begin{align}
E[T^{-1}]&=\frac{1}{2^{n/2}\Gamma(n/2)}\int^\infty_0 t^{-1}t^{n/2-1}e^{-t/2}\,dt\\
&=\frac{1}{2\,2^{\tfrac{n}{2}-1}(\tfrac{n}{2}-1)\Gamma(\tfrac{n}{2}-1)}\int^\infty_0t^{\frac{n-2}{2}-1}e^{-t/2}\\&=\frac{1}{n-2}
\end{align}$$